# this.getBoundingClientRect().top returns invalid value

Tags: javascript, jquery

All of these:

```
this.getBoundingClientRect().top
$(this).offset().top
$(this).position().top
```

return `144` for a relatively positioned element.
When I give this element:

```
position: absolute;
top: 144px;
```

it is way higher than it was when it was relative. The difference is about 22px. How can I get exact position?
Same thing happens in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect` gives coördinates relative to the screen's viewport. Did changing between _absolute_ and _relative_ change the element's position on screen? Are all scrollbars in the same places?

Comment: @PaulS. It didn't change position and there are no scrollbars.

Comment: @PaulS. I found out there is an element before- an img which does not have a declared height and it's set to float: left. After I gave it a height the top position for element below the img is reported just fine. Will try to post a demo.